# show logout link in navigation bar when logged in php

Tags: php, html, database

When user logged in, the login link on nav bar should be gone and logout link should appear how should i do it?

index.html:

```
<nav>
    <p class="menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></p> 
    <p class="menu"><a href="Product1.html">Products</a> </p> 
    <p class="menu"><a href="login.html">Login</a></p> 
    <p class="menu"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> 
    </nav>
```

Login.php file:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
session_start();

$password = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['Pass']);
$email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['EmailAdd']);
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Usermail='$email'");

//check email in db
 if ($result->num_rows == 0)
 {
 $_SESSION['message'] = "Email does not exist";

 print '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $_SESSION['message'] . 
 '");
</script>';
header("Location: ../register.html");
}
else
{
//get user array
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if ($password == $user['password'])
{
    $box = "Login successful";
    $_SESSION['email'] = $user['Usermail'];
    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;

echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Login Successful')
window.location.href='../index.html';
</SCRIPT>");

}
else
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Wrong password";

    header("Location: ../account.html");

    echo "failed";
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Wrong password")';
    echo '</script>';
   }
 }
 ?>
```

I've gone through some of the post in stack overflow and apply things like `if (!isset($_SESSION['email']))` and else statement on my index.php but its not working and i don't know what's the prob

Ps Previously was using index.php, since its not working so i change it back to index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your code is correctly validating the credential and setting the auth state in the session `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;`

You can do something like this:

```
<nav>
    <p class="menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></p> 
    <p class="menu"><a href="Product1.html">Products</a> </p> 
    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true): ?>
    <p class="menu"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p class="menu"><a href="login.html">Login</a></p> 
    <?php endif; ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;` this code should be included in the index.php file right or?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand that question. `$_SESSION['logged_in']` should be set to `true` _after_ user credentials have been validated.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){?>
    <p class="menu"><a href="login.html">Login</a></p> 
 <?php }

else
{?>    <p class="menu"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> 
<?php } ?>
```

try the above code, Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your nav:

```
    <?php    
    if($_SESSION['logged_in'] == "true"){
    echo '<p class="menu"><a href="logout.php">Login</a></p>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<p class="menu"><a href="login.html">Logout</a></p>';
    }
    ?>
```

It is not working because you use the .html extension instead of .php

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
    <p class="menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></p> 
    <p class="menu"><a href="Product1.html">Products</a> </p> 
    <?php if(empty($_SESSION['logged_in'])){ ?>
    <p class="menu"><a href="login.html">Login</a></p> 
    <?php } else{ ?>
    <p class="menu"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> 
    <?php } ?>

</nav>
```

Comment: This might cause an `undefined index` error when user arrives on the site for the first time and s/he isn't logged in - unless user bootstraps the application with a default state of `logged_in = false`

Comment: Updated the answer:)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<nav>
  <p class="menu"><a href="index.html">Home</a></p> 
  <p class="menu"><a href="Product1.html">Products</a></p> 
  <p class="menu">
     <?php if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in]) && $_SESSION['logged_in]) {?>
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
     <?php } else { ?>
        <a href="login.html">Login</a>
      <?php } ?>
  </p>
</nav>
```